# Using map to do "foreach" style call

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to get up the learning curve for Clojure, and I'm writing a simple program that should output a list of permutations of a given string. My recursive solution will call itself multiple times (so that there is a calling tree rather than a 1-D stack). I'm trying to understand how, given a list, I can call a function multiple times, giving it one element from the list per call. My current code is

```
(def permuteCat (
    fn [string printlist appendval]
    ( permute string (concat printlist (list appendval)) )
))

(def permuteRecurse (
    fn [string printlist appendlist]
    (
    map (partial permuteCat string printlist) appendlist
    )
))

(def permute (
    fn [string printlist] 
    (if ( == (count printlist) (.length string) )
        (println printlist)
        ( permuteRecurse string printlist ( range (- (.length string) (count printlist)) ) ) 
    )
)
)
```

However it looks like permuteCat() never gets called by permuteRecurse(). In a language like OCaml I'd curry permuteCat and use a map operator, but I understand that Clojure doesn't natively support currying. What's the preferred method for doing this? Or am I just way off-base and need to take a completely different approach?

Comment: You probably aren't seeing anything printed because map produces a lazy sequence. You can force iteration of the lazy sequence by wrapping the call to map inside dorun.

Comment: Blah. Just figured it out myself - I used doall rather than dorun but same effect. Coming from a C/Java background the lazy sequences stuff really throws a curveball when it comes to side-effects.

Comment: Lazy seqs are nice, but there are some gotchas with them. They don't play nicely with dynamically bound vars (the bindings might be out of scope by the time the seq elements are computed), and they can make stack traces show up in unexpected places.

Comment: Live and learn! Thanks for the input :D

Comment: you could also say (take n (iterate permute string)) or something like that

Answer (score 0):

[doseq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) is the idiomatic way to represent forced execution of foreach.
map produces a lazy sequence, so no execution occurs until the sequence is used. You can use doseq to write an imperative style foreach loop, but even better is if you separate the creation of your sequence from what you want to do with it (printing in this case, but maybe later you want to search through it instead).

```
; specify the sequence
(defn foo [v] (map inc v))

; print it
(doseq [v (foo [1 2 3])]
  (println v))
```